# How to make the same aspect ratio between axes in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I plot arrows:

```
plt.quiver([0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, -2, 4], [1, 2, -7], angles='xy', scale_units='xy', scale=1)
plt.xlim(-10, 10)
plt.ylim(-10, 10)
plt.show()
```

But it gives me axes with a different aspect ratio:
[image]

I added `plt.axis('equal')` after the first line and I got:
[image]

But it violated `xlim` and `ylim` conditions.

How to make proper scaling with correct limits?

Comment: You want to be using `plt.axis("scaled")` to change the box dimensions to follow the aspect of the data limits.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for square plot then set `figsize` of the plot

```
plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
plt.quiver([0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, -2, 4], [1, 2, -7], angles='xy', scale_units='xy', scale=1)
plt.xlim(-10, 10)
plt.ylim(-10, 10)
plt.show()
```

[image]

### Edit

As suggested by @importanceofbeingernest, setting `figsize` to square is not guaranteed to result in a square plot. The correct approach is to set the aspect ratio.

```
plt.quiver([0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, -2, 4], [1, 2, -7], angles='xy', scale_units='xy', scale=1)
plt.xlim(-10, 10)
plt.ylim(-10, 10)
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
plt.show()
```

Docs: https://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#aspect-ratio

Comment: A square figure does not necessarily give a square plot. In fact, if you take your image and analyse it in a graphics program you'll see that the axes is not square.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, you are correct, I have checked the docs. Updated with the solution that sets the aspect ratio.